# How to save a SQLCMD code as a executable file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I have a set of SQLCMD codes which are to be saved as exe files so that people can just execute the file rather than copy paste the code and run the command in command line.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert execution of sqlcmd to .exe?

Comment: yes @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your sql code to file for example script.sql and than create a batch file (for example run.bat) with below command

```
sqlcmd -U user -P passwrod -S SerwerName -i C:\script.sql
```

Comment: how can we create a bat file with this command this command just runs the script.sql code

Comment: Using text editor for example notepad++. You have to save a file as run.bat

Comment: @Parado i created run.bat how can we append this file into that?

Comment: sqlcmd -S 100H,1433\MSSQLSERVER -U sa -P dea -i C:\Main_Job.sql this is my sql code now I need this code to be a exe so that the person who is executing this just clicks a exe rather than copying this code in commandline and executing

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić yes but I couldnt even save my file as a bat yet

Comment: @Zack I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget you can also vote for the answer ;)