# I created some VBA that turns Excel data into SQL INSERTS. Is there a way to update SQL Server directly?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Currently, I take the copied SQL and paste into SQL Server Management Studio and then Execute. This is fine as it only takes a few seconds. However, I would like to know if there is a way to take my INSERTS or UPDATES and automatically apply them to SQL Server.

I've tried using Power Query but really I don't want to reinvent something if I can just add a line or two to automatically update. I can't find anything online to tie into what I already developed.

The code below is what I use to turn the columns into SQL INSERTs.  I would like to replace the copy to the Clipboard at the end of the code to something that will  INSERT directly into the SQL SERVER database Table.

```
Set Lad = NewFormat.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each cell In Lad
 cell.Value = "INSERT INTO GeoChem1(OrderID,SampleNumber,Matrix,Method,WellID,Site,DateCollected,DateReceived,CustomerName,Param," & _
  "ParamResults,Units,Dilution,Qualifier,RepLimit,AnalysisDate) VALUES(" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & "'" & "," & "'" & _
  cell.Offset(0, 3).Value & "'" & "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 4).Value & "'" & "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 5).Value & "'" & "," & cell.Offset(0, 6).Value & "," & _
  "'" & cell.Offset(0, 7).Value & "'" & "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 8).Value & "'" & "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 9).Value & "'" & "," & "'" & _
   cell.Offset(0, 10).Value & "'" & "," & cell.Offset(0, 11).Value & "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 12).Value & "'" & "," & cell.Offset(0, 13).Value & _
   "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 14).Value & "'" & "," & cell.Offset(0, 15).Value & "," & "'" & cell.Offset(0, 16).Value & "'" & ");"
  Next cell

 ''COPY TO CLIPBOard''
 Set Lad = NewFormat.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
Lad.Copy
```

Comment: How about save your query to a .sql file and then execute it with sqlcmd utilily? You can also save the command to a *.bat file and autorun it from scheduled task.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004258/) is how to execute sql file with sqlcmd

Comment: You also should read about how to use parameters with your queries. This code is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic ADO execute template I pulled out of my library for you. I suggest researching the topic.

also worth pointing out that youre looping through the sheet. Learn to dump to array and process that way.

This requires the correct reference to Microsoft Data Objects Lirbary

```
Private Sub zzz()
    Dim vbSql As String, cnnstr as string
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

    vbSql = "sql statement; "

    Set cnn = New Connection
    cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=yourserver;Initial Catalog=yourDB;User ID=UserName;Password=PassWord; Trusted_Connection=No"
    cnn.Open cnnstr
    cnn.Execute vbSql
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```